# Multiplying Integer to a Certain Power Using Loops

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that takes an integer base and integer exponent and multiply that integer to the certain power entered. But this code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```java
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner; 

import java.text.*;

public class Unit3_Lesson4_17 {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

    public static void main() {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   

        DecimalFormat mf = new DecimalFormat("'$'###,###,###.00");    
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###"); 


        int i, exp, base, answer;  

        String start;

        System.out.println("Hit Enter to Begin");
        start = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        base = in.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("Enter the exponent"); 
        exp = in.nextInt();

        answer = base;

        for (i=1; i<=exp; i++) {
            answer = answer * base;
        }

        System.out.println("The answer is " + answer);
        System.out.println("This program is over!"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is actually algorithmic in nature.

You are multiplying `answer` by `base`, `exp` times, but you also start `answer` with an initial value of `base`.  This means your output is `base`*`base`<sup>`exp`</sup>.

You need to either initialize `answer` to `1`, or change your for loop from

```
for (i=1; i<=exp; i++)
```

to

```
for (i=1; i<exp; i++)
```

Comment: Aw thanks a ton man! I was going to try that originally but didn't put much thought on it. Well, it's working now! Thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

Java already provides this functionality.

```
answer = Math.pow(base,exp);
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not OP's problem.

Comment: This problem required I used loops, but I know how Math.pow works. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I hate to see people struggle or write things in a less then optimal way.

Comment: Understood, and I'd rather use the Math.pow function, but my class requires I use different methods which is quite annoying.